# VistaDB - Connection property must be assigned Error

Tags: vistadb

I am getting the following error when I try to update one of the table in my vistadb.

```
VistaDB.Diagnostic.VistaDBSQLException was caught
HResult=1011
Message=
Error 1011 (Provider v. 5.0.4.1289): Connection property must be assigned Error #1011
Line #: 19; Column #: 5

  Source=VistaDB.5.NET40
  ErrorCode=1011
  ErrorId=1011
  LevelMessage=Error 1011 (Provider v. 5.0.4.1289): Connection property must be assigned Error #1011
Line #: 19; Column #: 5
  ColumnNo=5
  LineNo=19
  StackTrace:
       at VistaDB.Engine.SQL.BatchStatement.CheckBatchExceptions()
       at VistaDB.Engine.SQL.BatchStatement.NextResult(VistaDBPipe pipe)
       at VistaDB.Provider.VistaDBDataReader.ExecQuery(Int64& affectedRows)
       at VistaDB.Provider.VistaDBCommand.ExecQuery(Int64& affectedRows)
       at VistaDB.Provider.VistaDBCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
       at Motorola.Ardvarc.Data.Bases.Operations.BaseDBOperations
```

I searched online for this error but couldnt find any answers for this.Please help me with your thoughts on this.

Thanks
Murali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the issue myself. The problem is primary key ID is not set to the entry which you are trying to update. But I don't understand why VistaDB couldn't point me it is the referential integrity error.